# Algorithm to populate Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> type object

Tags: c#, dictionary

My DB table looks as follows:

```
Room        Item        Description
------------------------------------
Bedroom     Chair       Leather
Bedroom     Bed         Comfortable
Office      Desk        Very Small
Office      Book Shelf  Lot of Books
```

I want to populate this DB table into the following Dictionary type object

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>
```

How do I do this?

I started writing the code as follows but I could not go any further because I don't know how to populate it properly.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> roomfurnitures= new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>>();

Dictionary<string, string> furniture= new Dictionary<string, string>();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = this.m_cmdGetFurnitureByRoom.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string roomtype = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Room"));

                    string item = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Item"));
                    string description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Description"));

                    //I do not know how to populate the roomfurnitures dictionary poperly 
                }
            }
```

After roomfurnitures dictionary is populated properly, I want it to look like this. Please help.

```
Bedroom        Chair           Leather                   
               Bed             Comfortable
Office         Desk            VerySmall
               BookShelf       Lot of Books
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that the first time you encounter a new room you need to instantiate its Dictionary.  Add something like this at the location of your comment:

```
if (!roomfurnitures.ContainsKey(roomtype))
    roomfurnitures[roomtype] = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // the first time we've seen this

// get the dictionary for the specific room
var room = roomfurnitures[roomtype];

// now we can add the furniture to the room
room[item] = description;
```

Comment: -1 for using Dictionary.ContainsKey + indexer insertion. It's bad.

Comment: Brett, this is exactly what I was looking for. I tried it and it worked. Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `DataTable` filled with a `DataAdapter`, then use `Linq-To-DataSet`, `Enumerable.GroupBy` and `Enumerable.ToDictionary`:

```
var tblRooms = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
{
    da.Fill(tblRooms);
}
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> roomGroups =  tblRooms
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Room"))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g =>  g.ToDictionary(
        r => r.Field<string>("Item"), 
        r => r.Field<string>("Description")));
```